# selecting incorrect value HTML <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML:

```
 <select class="form" id="select" name="select">
            <option>number1</option>
            <option>number2</option>
    </select>

 <select name="organisation" class="form" id="cent" required>
            <option value="1">UK</option>
            <option value="2">SPAIN</option>
</select>
```

And another `<select>`:

```
 <select class="form" id="ssip" name="organisation">
    <option value="47" >US</option>
   <option value="48">UKRAINE</option>
</select>
```

`JQuery` to show on 1 - first select on 2 - second

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#select").each(function () {
        if (this.value == "1") {
            $('#cent').show();
            $('#ssip').hide();
        }
        if (this.value == "2") {
            $('#cent').hide();
            $('#ssip').show();
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that when i choose option number1 appears first select with values 1 and 2 but when i select UK with value 1 and click submit it's sending value 47 , of second select's first option..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling the opposite select when toggling the `select`s.  A control on a form will still be submitted if its display is set to `none`, however if the control is disabled it will not be submitted with the form.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(function () {
        if (this.value == "number1") {
            $('#cent').show().prop("disabled", false);
            $('#ssip').hide().prop("disabled", true);
        }
        if (this.value == "number2") {
            $('#cent').hide().prop("disabled", true);
            $('#ssip').show().prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/bTJsH/

Comment: Why looping elements with id "select" ? Should it be `$("select").each`

Comment: @Hardy Whoops!  I completely missed the each and thought it was a `change` event handler.

Comment: @Hardy .each is correct because it's mean is different only showing the exact selects you want

Comment: @HandesNebula Yeah.. loop that one element.. why not just read the element straight like `$('#select').value()`.. beyond belief..

Comment: @Hardy hmm it's correct also but that wasn't problem :)

Comment: using the disabled attr to prevent submission?

Comment: @NathanielCurrier To prevent a parameter from being passed on submit.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to loop one select box..

```
$("#select").each(function () {
```

There can be only one element with id "select". You should check like:

```
if ($("#select").value() == "1") { ..
```

And you don't even have values in your first select options..

Comment: So you loop each element with ID select? Can't understand.. there can be just one element with id "select"..

Comment: there is no need for a loop here. bind to events instead and apply your show/hide logic to the collections returned by the jquery selector

Answer (score 1):

i might suggest something like this

```
$('#select').on('change', function() {

   var selected = this.selectedIndex;

   $('.orgs').hide();

   switch(selected) {
        case 1:
            $('#ssip').show();
            break;
        case 2: 
            $('#cent').show();
            break;
    }
});
```

here is an working example http://jsfiddle.net/pixelchemist/7ZGwy/